# value of javascript object not changing (pass by reference)

Tags: javascript, closures, pass-by-reference

```
function outerFunction(x){
    return function(y){
        x=x+1;
        console.log(x+y);
    }
}
var myVal = new Number(2); //myVal is an object
console.log(myVal); //prints Number{[[PrimitiveValue]]: 2}

var innerFunction  = outerFunction(myVal); //I'm passing myVal obj
innerFunction(10)   //13
innerFunction(10)   //14
innerFunction(10)   //15

console.log(myVal);  //prints Number{[[PrimitiveValue]]: 2} instead of 5?
```

I expected the last `console.log` to print `Number{[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}`, since I passed `myVal object` to the `outerFunction` and in JS objects are passed by reference, why it didn't print 5?

Comment: Re: "in JS objects are passed by reference": That's not true (as your code demonstrates).

Comment: @ruakh  I changed my code to var myObj = {a:2} and passed myObj to the outerfunction..and did x.a = x.a +1 ;  and console.log indeed changed to {a:5}  which confirms objects are passed by reference

Comment: @ruakh Objects are passed as a copy of a reference, so you have to distinguish between mutation and reassignment

Comment: @WildWidow: That's not what "pass by reference" means. Yes, there's only one object (unlike in, say, C++, where the function would get a copy of the object); but the variables themselves are distinct. (Don't feel bad; this is actually a really common source of confusion.)

Comment: (In C++ terms: in JavaScript you only ever have an implicit pointer to each object; there's no way to refer to an object directly, nor any way to take an explicit pointer. So the function has a *distinct* pointer to the *same* object. It's similar to pass-by-reference, until you try to reassign the local variable and find that this only has local effect.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple explanation using console.log (do check what javascript prints in console in this case):

```
function outerFunction(x){

    return function(y){

        console.log("type of x", typeof x); 
        console.log("value x:",x);
        console.log("value y:",y);

        x=x+1;
        console.log(x+y);
    }

}


var myVal = new Number(2); //myVal is an object
console.log(myVal); //prints Number{[[PrimitiveValue]]: 2}

var innerFunction  = outerFunction(myVal); //I'm passing myVal obj
innerFunction(10)   //13
innerFunction(10)   //14
innerFunction(10)   //15

console.log("type of myval",typeof myVal);

console.log(myVal);  //prints Number{[[PrimitiveValue]]: 2} instead of 5?//
```

Here what is happening in your code.

==> Firstly you cannot add two objects in javascript using the + operator. So javascript converts it to a Number or a String (in this case a number as you are passing a number itself, which is a primitive type)

==> The inner function that you are returning has an outer reference of X from the outer function. (because of closures)

==> Each time you increment X, the value of x in the scope of outer function changes but it has now no effect on the global "myVal" variable(type object) as javascript considers the local X as primitive type (explained in the first point, which are passed by value and not by reference)

==> So the global value remains the same and X keeps changing which is accessed by inner function, that is why you see 13,14,15 as answers

Hope it helps

Comment: it is called currying

Comment: @Wild **This is an insufficient response**: `myVal` isn't a function but an object. Objects are passed by sharing a copy of the reference. The correct evaluation strategy is thus **pass by sharing**. So the OP's assumption is almost right, that `Objects` are passed by (a copy of a) reference. With this evaluation strategy you have to distinguish mutation `let n = new Number(2); n.x = true;` and reassignment `let n = new Number(2); n = 3;`

Comment: @lven , can you elaborate a bit on your point? Also there was a typing error in my point no. 3 which I have corrected.